# Php echo onClick JS Function (pass string):: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick, echo

Using simple PHP and Javascripet (no JSON, AJAX, or anything fancy) I am trying to echo a javascript onClick event function. This onClick function takes two strings, and as a start I want to see those strings using the "alert" function. Below is my code in the html/php file::

```
    <DIV id="show">
    !-- few more lines here  -->
    <?PHP
    $CONN = mysqli_connect($SERVER_w, $USER_w, $PASS_w, $DBNAME_w);
    $SQL = "SELECT * from COUNTRYTABLE";
    $RESULT = mysqli_query($CONN, $SQL);   
    $NUM_RECORDS = mysqli_num_rows($RESULT); 
    echo "<BR>";
    for($x = 1; $x<=$NUM_RECORDS; $x++)
    {  $ROW = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT, MYSQLI_ASSOC);    

    //the main line::
    echo "<button onClick=\"Show_Pair(\"" . $ROW['CONTINENT'] . "\",\"" . 
    $ROW['COUNTRY'] . "\")\"> Show! </button> <BR>";

    }
    mysqli_free_result($RESULT);
    mysqli_close($CONN);
    ?>   
    </DIV>
```

The Javascript function is a simple one:

```
    function Show_Pair_In_Alert(CON, CTR)
    {
   alert(CON + CTR);
    }
```

When the PHP evaluates, the HTML looks like follows:

```
    <DIV id="show">
    <p>CONTINENT - COUNTRY Linkage: </p><BR><BR><button 
    onClick="Show_Pair_In_Alert("AFRICA_EAST","Comoros")">Show</button> <BR>
    <button onClick="Show_Pair_In_Alert("AFRICA_EAST","Eritrea")">Show</button>
    <BR>
    <button onClick="Show_Pair_In_Alert("AFRICA_EAST","Kenya")">Show</button> 
    <BR> 
    </DIV>
```

HOWEVER, when I look at the developer tools/console thingy in Chrome, I see the following error::
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }, and this error occurrs just above the end of the  and below the last button.. theres a red circle with a yellow cross in it.. as can be seen in the image below

[image: Error in Chrome]

Would appreciate any feedback.. just to reiterate.. im not using any JSON, AJAX, anything... just trying to achieve something fairly complex for my begineer level :P.. thank you very much for your assistance in advance!!

Comment: You need to fix your quotes. You have double quotes inside double quotes which is causing the problem. Try keeping the outside ones and replacing the inside ones with single quotes?

Comment: It might be easier/clearer if you dropped out of PHP to output that line. `//the main line::
?>
<button onClick="Show_Pair("<?php echo $ROW['CONTINENT']; ?>","<?php echo $ROW['COUNTRY']; ?>")"> Show! </button> <BR>
<?php`

Comment: @JonStirling, thanks that was what fixed it!! i felt it could be something to do with too many double quotes ("'), tried to insert single quote using \' but then the \ was appearing in the output. I later tried without, and it works.. thank you so much!  ,

Comment: @Dave thanks to you too. i guess I could try it this way too, it makes sense. Just a beginneer so a bit cautious of jumping in and out of PHP (who knows what could happen), but I will try it. Thanks a lot!